# Why aren't the SDL_Rect* arguments of SDL_BlitSurface const?

Tags: c++, c, sdl

```
int SDL_BlitSurface(SDL_Surface *src, SDL_Rect *srcrect, SDL_Surface *dst, SDL_Rect *dstrect);
```

Why are the srcrect and dstrect arguments not const? Are they modified in the function? At the moment I'm const-casting my Sprite class member variables to use BlitSurface... It seems silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_BlitSurface) specifies that `dstrect`, if non-NULL, is modified to contain the resulting clipped rectangle.  `srcrect` is not modified, so it very well could be made `const`.  Why?  Who knows.  I'd guess that it was probably an oversight by the people who wrote SDL.

Answer (score 3):

Because [they're modified](http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/f14cf9d71233/src/video/SDL_surface.c#l474).